# Write a TimeSpan on an Excel File

Tags: excel, vb.net, time

I'm making a vb.net program where I write on an Excel File some data. That's not a problem so far!
However, I'm having trouble on writing TimeSpans on the file.

For example, on the code:

```
Sub DataExport()
    'Create a bridge between Console and Excel:
    Dim ExcelBridge As Excel.Application
    ExcelBridge = New Excel.Application
    Dim NewWorkbook As Excel.Workbook = ExcelBridge.Workbooks.Open("P:\HelpDesk\Definitions\Models\RPMAN.xlsm")
    NewWorkbook.Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    'Create Desktop folders if they don't exist:
    If Dir(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop) & "\Reports", vbDirectory) = "" Then
        MkDir(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop) & "\Reports")
    End If
    If Dir(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop) & "\Reports\HelpDesk", vbDirectory) = "" Then
        MkDir(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop) & "\Reports\HelpDesk")
    End If
    'Test variables:
    Dim test01 As Integer = 2
    Dim test02 As String = "FieldA"
    Dim test03 As String = "FieldB"
    Dim test04 As String = "FieldC"
    Dim test05 As Date = DateSerial(2017, 1, 1)
    Dim test06 As Date = Now()
    Dim test07 As TimeSpan = TimeSpan.Parse("1.12:03:55")
    Dim test08 As String = "FieldD"
    Dim test09 As TimeSpan = TimeSpan.Parse("3.20:43:07")
    Dim test10 As String = "FieldE"
    'Write Excel file:
    With NewWorkbook.Sheets("RESUMO")
        .cells(3, 1).formular1c1 = test01
        .cells(3, 2).formular1c1 = test02
        .cells(3, 3).formular1c1 = test03
        .cells(3, 4).formular1c1 = test04
        .cells(3, 5).formular1c1 = test05
        .cells(3, 6).formular1c1 = test06
        .cells(3, 7).formular1c1 = test07
        .cells(3, 8).formular1c1 = test08
        .cells(3, 9).formular1c1 = test09
        .cells(3, 10).formular1c1 = test10
    End With
    'Save Excel file:
    NewWorkbook.SaveAs(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop) & "\Relatórios\HelpDesk\ITreport" & Format(Now(), "yyyyMMddHHmmss") & ".xlsm")
    'Close Excel file
    NewWorkbook.Close()
End Sub
```

I get an error on the line

```
.cells(3, 7).formular1c1 = test07
```

It simply doesn't let me write it.

With an `On Error Resume Next`, the code writes everything else but both TimeSpans.

Probably this issue has a simple solution, But I really don't see it.
Any help will be very appreciated. And, as always, thank you all in advance.

Comment: How about `.cells(3, 7) = test07`?

Comment: No! That doesn't work either...

Comment: `Dim test07 As TimeSpan = DateTime.Parse("1.12:03:55")`?

Comment: Sorry! Any combination of your last suggestions works...

Comment: The obviously the problem is in the TimeSpan. Try to make it ToString and simply put the value there. Something like `.cells(3, 7).formular1c1 = test07.ToString(@"dd\.hh\:mm\:ss")`

Comment: what error are you getting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `System.TimeSpan` does not have a directly corresponding Excel type.  You will need to convert its value to something that Excel can understand.  Excel stores date-time values as an offset from a base date as a Double that represents the total number of whole days and fractional days from said offset.

However, the TimeSpan structure has the `TotalDays` property that will work for as an Excel date-time value.  The Excel cell should have a NumberFormat set to properly display the value ("d:HH:mm:ss").

```
NewWorkbook.Sheets("RESUMO").Cells(3, 7).Value2 = test07.TotalDays
NewWorkbook.Sheets("RESUMO").Cells(3, 7).NumberFormat = "d:HH:mm:ss"
```

Comment: It worked! Thanks a lot. However I used the code `NewWorkbook.Sheets("RESUMO").Cells(3, 7).FormulaR1C1 = Format(test07.TotalDays, "d:HH:mm:ss")`...