# Set Excel cell to TimeSpan value

Tags: c#, excel, datetime, gembox-spreadsheet

I need to create an Excel file with a column containing time values (`TimeSpan` objects).

I'm using [GemBox.Spreadsheet](https://www.gemboxsoftware.com/spreadsheet) and I can create a column with date values (`DateTime` objects) by using either `ExcelCell.Value` property or `ExcelCell.SetValue` method:

```cs
var workbook = new ExcelFile();
var worksheet = workbook.Worksheets.Add("Sheet1");

worksheet.Cells["A1"].Value = "Start Dates";

// Set cell value to DateTime with Value property.
worksheet.Cells["A2"].Value = DateTime.Today;

// Set cell value to DateTime with SetValue method.
worksheet.Cells["A3"].SetValue(DateTime.Today);

workbook.Save("output.xlsx");
```

But neither of those work for `TimeSpan`.
When using the properly, I get `NotSupportedException`, and when using the method, I get a compiler error.

What's confusing to me is that I can load an existing Excel file with cells containing time values and read them.
So, there must be a way how I can write them as well, right?

Comment: What is the exptected output of cells with `TimeSpan` value? How do you want them to appear in Excel.

Comment: Like time values, the same that I get when manually writing from Microsoft Excel values  "12:30:00" or "999:59:59".

Comment: There is no direct TimeSpan equivalent in Excel. You should set the value as number and use excel formatting to show. Example here; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43896427/write-a-timespan-on-an-excel-file . Also check `TimeValue` function, it can help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Excel files don't have separate types for dates and for times.

When reading those cells with time values, you may notice that they have `ExcelCell.ValueType` set to `CellValueType.DateTime`. In other words, the `ExcelCell.Value` contains the `DateTime` object.

Also, if you check the `ExcelCell.Style.NumberFormat` you'll notice it defines some time format like "h:mm:ss".

Anyway, try using this `SetValue` extension method:

```cs
public static class GemBoxHelper
{
    public static void SetValue(this ExcelCell cell, TimeSpan span, string format = "[h]:mm:ss")
    {
        DateTime start = cell.Worksheet.Parent.Use1904DateSystem ?
            new DateTime(1904, 1, 1) :
            new DateTime(1899, 12, 30);

        DateTime date = start.Add(span);
        DateTime leapYearBug = new DateTime(1900, 3, 1);

        if (date < leapYearBug)
            date = date.AddDays(1);

        cell.SetValue(date);
        cell.Style.NumberFormat = format;
    }
}
```

Also, here is an example showing how to use it:

```cs
var workbook = new ExcelFile();
var worksheet = workbook.Worksheets.Add("Sheet1");

worksheet.Cells["A1"].SetValue(new TimeSpan(12, 30, 00));
worksheet.Cells["A2"].SetValue(new TimeSpan(999, 59, 59));

workbook.Save("output.xlsx");
```